# Symfony Components without the full stack framework (Episode 2)

Tags: php, symfony, no-framework

I'm only using Symfony DI, Http, Kernel, Routing components in my project following Create your own PHP Framework (https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html).
Project, on which I specify, that @cerad was of great help. Thanks again.
It's ok with Service and Controller dependency injection.

Cf. [Symfony Components without the full stack framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301368/symfony-components-without-the-full-stack-framework) (Episode 1)
And
https://github.com/Monnomcjo/symfony-simplex

But now I encounter a new difficulty with instantiate repository in dependency injection.

I added symfony/orm-pack to use ServiceEntityRepository.

**UPDATED :**

As specified in the comments my concern is a problem of approach.

My question is poorly put and the context is not sufficiently clear. Still in a learning environment, I try to implement the concepts of Clean Architecture and Domain Driven Design.

In this idea of ​​partitioning and independence, I also try to better master my Framework by starting from almost nothing, to add as I go, only what I need.

Still following the comments I no longer use symfony / orm-pack but doctrine / dbal.

There is still a lot to do but it works.

#container.php

```
// Doctrine
$containerBuilder->register(\ExampleApp\Domain\Client\Entity\ClientRepository::class, \Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\Client\DoctrineClientRepository::class)
    ->setArguments([new Reference('service_container')]);

$containerBuilder->register(\ExampleApp\Domain\Client\UseCase\GetClient\GetClient::class, \ExampleApp\Domain\Client\UseCase\GetClient\GetClient::class)
    ->setArguments([new Reference(\ExampleApp\Domain\Client\Entity\ClientRepository::class)]);

$containerBuilder->register(\ExampleApp\Presentation\Client\GetClientHtmlPresenter::class, \ExampleApp\Presentation\Client\GetClientHtmlPresenter::class);

$containerBuilder->register(\Infrastructure\View\GetClientView::class, \Infrastructure\View\GetClientView::class);

$containerBuilder->register(\Infrastructure\Controller\ClientController::class, \Infrastructure\Controller\ClientController::class)
    ->setArguments([
        new Reference(\ExampleApp\Domain\Client\UseCase\GetClient\GetClient::class),
        new Reference(\ExampleApp\Presentation\Client\GetClientHtmlPresenter::class),
        new Reference(\Infrastructure\View\GetClientView::class)
]);
```

Returns are ok now.

https://github.com/Monnomcjo/symfony-simplex is updated too.

Next step, add .env, and conf files type services.yaml

Comment: It seems you did not register your repository class in the Service Container. EntityRepository classes need an EntityManager with an open database connection. The DoctrineBundle provides an abstract `ServiceEntityRepository`-class that helps the Service Container to instantiate these classes through the ManagerRegistry. This helps autowiring the repositories. If you don't want to use that class you will have to manually register each repository with the container instead.

Comment: Hello @dbrumann. The purpose of the project is a case study. I'm trying to better understand how a Framework and its low-level components work. I have already made good progress on the subject with my previous post. In particular on the injection of dependencies in the services and controllers. So I'm actually looking to manually register each repository with the container.

Comment: I helped a bit with your Episode 1 question so trust me whan I say that this is fundamentally the wrong approach.  The DoctrineBundle is specifically about interfacing the independent Doctrine library with a Symfony Framework application.  You need to install the Doctrine libraries, study the startup code in the Doctrine docs and then create your own services.  Not an easy task.

Comment: By the way, there is a Symfony Reddit forum that might be a better choice for these sorts of big picture questions.  I'm actually a but surprised that your first question did not get closed.

Comment: Thx @Cerad, I'll follow your advice."my first question did not get closed?"

Comment: FYI @Cerad, I took my case study forward to something that works;) Thank you again for the quality of your feedback.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any question in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your problem right now is with the missing `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` I think the best way to see how Symfony does it, is to look at the DoctrineBundle. Specifically at [DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/2.2.x/DependencyInjection/DoctrineExtension.php#L407-L410) and the [Configuration](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/2.2.x/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L324) from which the config values are received. You might also want to take a look at the [service definitions](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/2.2.x/Resources/config/orm.xml#L100-L102).

The Extension class takes the configuration (usually in your config/packages/doctrine.yaml) that is validated through the Configuration and then updates the service definitions under Resources/config. This approach is rather complex, but it will help you see how things are connected in Symfony.

Alternatively you can look at the [Doctrine Docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/getting-started.html#obtaining-the-entitymanager) to see how to get an EntityManager and then convert this into Symfony Service Container registration:

```php
$isDevMode = true;
$proxyDir = null;
$cache = null;
$useSimpleAnnotationReader = false;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode, $proxyDir, $cache, $useSimpleAnnotationReader);
// or if you prefer yaml or XML
//$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yaml"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

You can see the EntityManager::create in the service definition link above. How you do this in your application largely depends on how close you want to build it to Symfony and what and how you want to configure around Doctrine.

Comment: Thank you @dbrumann, this is exactly the right approach. I updated my GitHub repo. And everything is ok. If it is only from now on beyond the exercise "to create its Framework" is added the concepts of Clean Archi. and DDD.