# Symfony HttpKernel Component not resolving controllers nor showing any errors in standalone setup

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-kernel

The HttpKernel component from Symfony is, alone, a powerful component to deal with the `Request` to `Response` conversion during the Client browser's HTTP Requests. I have been, however, struggling to get things to work as expected.

When I visit the default route I get the Welcome page which looks pretty cool.

[image]

I have attempted a few things to get things to work with two of the custom routes that I have defined.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

$routes = $container->get(RouteCollection::class);

$routes->add('hello', new Route('/hello/{name}', [
        '_controller' => function (Request $request): Response {
            return new Response(
                sprintf("Hello %s", $request->get('name'))
            );
        }]
));

$routes->add('reports', new Route('/reports', [
    '_controller' => ['\Demo\Invoice\App\Controller\ReportsController::listAction'],
]));
```

Furthermore, I have defined my controller as a service as shown below:

```php
// Controllers
$services->set(InvoiceReports::class)
   ->arg('$twig', service(Environment::class))
   ->public();
```

Having attempted to use the `ContainerControllerResolver`, apart from the `ControllerResolver` that both comes with the said component, I have also tried to write my own Controller Resolver borrowing from the **FrameworkBundle**.

[image]

Both custom routes show blank screens when I visit them on the browser, and I have no idea what is going on with all three Controller resolvers I have tried to work with. Even when I have enabled `Debug::enable()` nothing shows up unless it is a fatal error.

Below is how I setup my Kernel implementation so as to take advantage of this powerful component.

```php
namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver;

/**
 * @see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#a-full-working-example
 */
return static function (ContainerConfigurator $container): void {
    $services = $container->services();

    $services->set(RouteCollection::class)
        ->public();

    $services->set(Request::class)
        ->factory([Request::class, 'createFromGlobals'])
        ->public();

    $services->alias(RequestInterface::class, Request::class)
        ->public();

    $services->set(RequestContext::class)
        ->public();

    $services->set(UrlMatcher::class)
        ->args([
            service(RouteCollection::class),
            service(RequestContext::class),
        ])
        ->public();

    $services->set(RequestStack::class)
        ->public();

    $services->set(RouterListener::class)
        ->args([
            service(UrlMatcher::class),
            service(RequestStack::class),
        ])
        ->public();

    $services->set(EventDispatcherInterface::class, EventDispatcher::class)
        ->call('addSubscriber', [service(RouterListener::class)])
        ->public();

    $services->set(ControllerResolver::class)
        ->arg('$logger', service(LoggerInterface::class))
        ->public();

    $services->set(ArgumentResolver::class)
        ->public();

    $services->set(HttpKernel::class)
        ->args([
            service(EventDispatcherInterface::class),
            service(ControllerResolver::class),
            service(RequestStack::class),
            service(ArgumentResolver::class),
        ])
        ->public();

    $services->set(Response::class)
        ->public();
};
```

As mentioned before the above configuration seems to work, except it is so frustrating to not know what I am doing wrong when it comes to defining my class-based controllers.

**How can I get my agnostic framework to resolve my controller classes?**

I have my codebase hosted on [github](https://github.com/scruffycoderofficial/agnostic-framework) should anyone be interested to poke around it.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html

Comment: Using the kernel standalone can be tricky.  From your github it seems like you have quite a bit code. Just seems like routing would have been tested before adding all that other stuff. I'm guessing the project was copied from someplace else? In any event nothing really stands out as being wrong but I don't have the time right now to test. I would add the Symfony dump component and then just go with the basics. Verify the static config functions are being called then verify the route listener is being called then see what the controller resolver is doing.

Comment: Cerad the codebase was not copied anywhere else, unfortunately. I started working on this Monday and have been struggling with getting my controllers to be resolved. With the link that @yivi suggested above I have already refactored my code to a working state except I still cannot inject things through the constructor. I will try to override the ControllerResolver such that I can be able to use the ContainerAwareTrait to access some of the services I need or just try to test by defining the controller as a service. Very much appreciate that you looked at the repo.

Comment: Would it be possible to use Symfony all the way? If not, why not check through XDebug what is happening?

Comment: I am trying to write a demo application that uses no framework at all. This is a requirement that my potential employer has put forth and so I have chosen to use the Symfony Component to build my little agnostic framework from which I can then code my solution, thanks.

Comment: Hello all, as of yesterday I was able to achieve what I wanted with the help of @yivi. I will update the answer as soon as possible when I finish my assessment. Thank you a lot for your input, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Look like you have things under control but it also looks like you are using the ControllerResolver class instead of the ContainerControllerResolver which you need to access the controller services. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301368/symfony-components-without-the-full-stack-framework/66317793#66317793) might help unless you have already gotten past that.

Comment: @Cerad yes I have. I did change things around and will do a clean-up later on to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the link provided by @yivi I was able to get things to work. Below are the steps I have taken after reconfiguring my stack.

### Route Definitions

The route definitions did not change much as they were in the correct order.

```php
$routes->add('reports', new Routing\Route('/', [
    '_controller' => [CoolStuff\App\Controller\ReportsController::class, 'showAction'],
]));
```

The Symfony Routing Component is independent of the Symfony Dependency Injection component. Through Symfony HttpKernel Component, we can link the two together to achieve what I wanted through the provided controller resolvers.

### Controller as a Service

It is also crucial to make sure that the Controller class can be resolved through the container by registering it as a service.

```php
$services->set(ReportsController::class)
        ->arg('$authService', service(AuthService::class))
        ->arg('$invoiceService', service(InvoiceService::class))
        ->arg('$twig', service(Environment::class))
        ->arg('$log', service(LoggerInterface::class))
        ->tag('controller.service_arguments')
        ->public();
```

Since we have turned auto-wiring support off we also have to mark the service as public so that we can be able to use the `get` method when resolving it out of the container. Furthermore, our service has to be tagged with `controller.service_arguments`. The arguments are pretty standard, but they are the crux of the issue I was having because I was using an incorrect Controller Resolver amongst other things.

### The Controller Resolver Binding

I have changed the binding of the `ControllerResolverInterface`; instead of using `ControllerResolver` I settled for the `ContainerControllerResolver` so that we can rely on the Container to resolve our Controller class definitions. This way we can be able to inject the dependencies we need through our Controller's construct method.

```php
$container->register('controller_resolver', ContainerControllerResolver::class)
    ->setArguments([$container, new Reference(LoggerInterface::class)]);
```

With the three points above I was able to solve my problem and had everything working perfectly from the MVC point of view.