# Symfony Routing component standalone - how to add arguments for a controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony components 5.x

My `composer.json` file looks like this

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "9.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^5.4",
        "symfony/config": "^5.4",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.10",
        "symfony/cache": "^5.4",
        "twig/twig": "3.0",
        "symfony/security-core": "^5.4",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^5.4",
        "symfony/security-http": "^5.4",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^5.4",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "^5.4",
        "symfony/routing": "^5.4"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the routing component to define some routes. Currently I only have 1 route defined like this

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes->add(
    'shop_info',
    new Route('/api/v1/shop/info', [
        '_controller' => [ShopController::class, 'index'],
    ])
);
```

The route itself works fine.

The problem arises when trying to instantiate the controller itself.

The `index` function expects an argument.

```
class ShopController
{
    public function index(AgentRepository $agentRepository): JsonResponse
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['test' => 1234]);
    }
}
```

I would also be perfectly happy with constructor arguments(although some may not be used, so I'd prefer method arguments).

```
class ShopController
{
    private AgentRepository $agentRepository;

    public function __construct(AgentRepository $agentRepository)
    {
        $this->agentRepository = $agentRepository;
    }

    public function index(): JsonResponse
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['test' => 1234]);
    }
}
```

`AgentRepository` itself also has a few arguments of its own.

I'm at a loss how I would instantiate these arguments. I was hoping I could use the DI container but it doesn't seem to do that by default and I can't figure out how to add a custom `ArgumentResolver`. Even if I did I would still have a `n` number of cascading arguments to resolve so that doesn't help much.

I tried following this "guide" from the symfony official docs/site https://symfony.com/doc/5.x/create_framework/dependency_injection.html but it doesn't go into much detail on how to use the components besides a very simple introduction.

I'm looking for a more detailed example of how to solve this issue. A link to a article/guide/whatever is also fine.

Comment: There is a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77872839/symfony-httpkernel-component-not-resolving-controllers-nor-showing-any-errors-in) on the same subject. There is a source code repo to look at. The owner says that have it working though I don't know if they updated the code.  You do want to use the ContainerControllerResolver if you want to inject dependencies into the constructor.  There are also resolver for action method arguments but those take more config. These sorts of issues are why the framework exists.

Comment: I would use the full framework if I could. This is for a very legacy project that I'm trying to modernize a bit. I'll take a look at the question, thanks.

Comment: He ended up doing what I was doing just different, he has a [container resolver](https://github.com/scruffycoderofficial/agnostic-framework/blob/feature/base-framework/app/bootstrap/app.php#L94) which is much cleaner indeed. Passing the container also leads to other issues unfortunately, like being unable to dump and cache the container...which is my next issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Somewhere in the docs there is a section on using the framework with legacy projects.  You do you but I can almost guarantee that each time you get past one issue, another will pop up. Caching the container is not as easy as it might seem.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to that section? For the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/migration.html is a good starting point.

Comment: This may be viable. The project is not yet in the stage were I'd feel confident in migrating, but hopefully soon.

Answer (score 0):

**I'll start by pointing out that this is a terrible idea since you won't be able to cache the container once it's compiled since it's a circular dependency on itself.**

I managed to get something working. I have no idea if this is the correct way. It works but it feels very fragile.

I crated a new listener that listens to `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER_ARGUMENTS` this will run whenever this event happens, which is whenever a controller is going to be resolved.

You can see it in the symfony github too - https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/7.0/HttpKernel.php#L173 (this is for symfony 7.0 but the principle and line number for that matter is the same for 5.x)

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerArgumentsEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;


class ControllerArgumentResolver implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder;

    public function __construct(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder)
    {
        $this->containerBuilder = $containerBuilder;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER_ARGUMENTS => ['onKernelControllerArguments', 256]
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelControllerArguments(KernelEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var ControllerArgumentsEvent $event */
        if(0 === count($event->getArguments())) {
            return;
        }

        $args = [];
        foreach($event->getArguments() as $argument) {
            if(is_string($argument) && $this->containerBuilder->has($argument)) {
                $args[] = $this->containerBuilder->get($argument);
            } else {
                $args[] = $argument;
            }
        }

        $event->setArguments($args);
    }
}
```

The constructor parameter is the symfony DI Container. I figured it's a easy way to solve the cascading dependecy part.

To do that you'd need to add the container itself to the listener.

```
$container->register('listener.controller_argument_resolver', ControllerArgumentResolver::class)
    ->setArguments([$container])
;
```

Then, when defining my route(s) I added an extra argument

```
$routes->add(
    'shop_info',
    new Route('/api/v1/shop/info', [
        '_controller' => [ShopController::class, 'index'],
        'agentRepository' => AgentRepository::class <-- THIS IS THE NEW ARGUMENT
    ])
);
```

I also needed the `Request` object in my controller.

```
class ShopController
{
    public function index(AgentRepository $agentRepository, Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

But it seems to get automagically resolved. I didn't bother looking how, but adding a break point in my listener its clear that it's already resolved

[image]

This feels like a fragile solution. God knows how many bugs that listener has that I'll probably encounter months later.

I'm still very open to suggestions. I won't be accepting my answer. I posted it mostly for other people.